# How to query for rows inserted after a certain date

Tags: python, oracle, oracle10g, cx-oracle

I'm working with Python2, Oracle10g, and cxOracle.

In my Python code, I have a certain datetime, like this:

```
last_check_timestamp = datetime.today() - timedelta(hours = 1)
print last_check_timestamp
>>> last_check_timestamp = 2016-03-14 11:13:06.743626
print type(last_check_timestamp)
>>> type(last_check_timestamp) = <type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

I want to run a query that retrieves all the rows inserted after said datetime. This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
    query_string = ("SELECT * FROM {0} "
                    "WHERE SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) >= '{1}'".\
                    format(db_name, self.last_check_timestamp.timetuple()))
    logger.info("query_string = \n%s\n" % query_string)
```

So the resulting query string that is received by Oracle is this:

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.DUAL
WHERE SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) >= 'time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=14, tm_hour=11, tm_min=23, tm_sec=26, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=74, tm_isdst=-1)'
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

How should this date comparison be done in order for Oracle to acept the query?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the rowdependencies is enabled the last SCN is stored at data block level not on row level. In order to have the SCN number for a row level you need to on the rowdependencies for a table.

```
select * from tablename where SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN)='14-MAR-16 02.01.05.000000000 PM';
```

I believe you are passing the timestamp in incorrect format to oracle as time.struct_time is not an oracle function

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.DUAL
WHERE SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN) >= 'time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=14, tm_hour=11, tm_min=23, tm_sec=26, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=74, tm_isdst=-1)'
```